# What is $previous in Exception class?

Tags: php, exception

What does `$previous` in the `Exception` constructor argument denote? How could I use it?

```
    class MyException extends \Exception {

    private $message;
    private $code;


    public function __construct($message,$code,\Exception $previous=null){
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->code = isset($code) ? $code : 0;
        parent::__construct($message,$code,$previous);      
    }       
}
```

I didn't find anything in the [API Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php)

Comment: [See this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)  specifically the user contributed notes are helpful....

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php this documentation. `$previous` previously thrown exception object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you throw an exception because you caught an exception, you can add the original exception as `$previous`. That means you can actually "nest" exceptions:

```
try {
    throw new FooException('Foo exception');
} catch (FooException $e) {
    $code = 1;
    throw new BarException('Bar exception', $code, $e);
}
```

You can then loop over the exception "stack" instead of just the exception caught, providing you with more context.

```
while($e instanceof \Exception) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $e = $e->getPrevious();
}
```

Now, you would probably use this if you're implementing a library that can throw an exception, but you'd like to wrap that exception in your own. That way, your clients' code only needs to know of *your* exceptions, and not that of the exceptions that the dependencies of your code has, while not losing any kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

the reason is that PHP 5.3 introduces **nested exceptions** as a default part of the PHP base Exception class. While the above code will work, if you are utilizing PHP 5.3, you can pass any **previous exception as a third argument** , and use the **Exception::getPrevious()** method to get a previously raised exception.

argument of a previous exception, allowing you to nest the exceptions. When preparing to log your exception, you can opt to iterate through any possible previously thrown and nested exceptions, and log any of the data you need.

**What is nesting?** Nesting is the ability to catch a particular exception, create a new exception object to be thrown with a reference to the original exception. This then allows the caller access to both the exception thrown from within the consumed library of the more well known type, but also access to the exception that originated this exceptional behavior as well.

**Why is this useful?** Typically, this is most useful in code that consumes other code that throws exceptions of its own type. This might be code that utilizes the 
for more 
http://www.brandonsavage.net/exceptional-php-nesting-exceptions-in-php/